# How to load an ImageView with a png file without using "setImageBitmap()"?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-file

I do some processing (quality improvement and a bit of resizing) on a `Bitmap` object and then store it using `bitmap.compress()` function by giving a file name "myfile.png".

```
newbitmap = processImage(bitmap);
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("myfile.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
newbitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
```

Now I want to load this image in an `ImageView` but I cant use `setImageBitmap()` to do that. Is there any alternative ?

The reason I cant use `setImageBitmap()` is that I am using `RemoteViews` for a widget, and using bitmap method leads to **Failed Binder Transaction** error when the image is large.

I tried to set image uri using the code below but the image does not load on the `ImageView`:

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

File internalFile = context.getFileStreamPath("myfile.png");
Uri internal = Uri.fromFile(internalFile);
rv.setImageViewUri(R.id.widgetImageView, internal);
updateAppWidget(awID, rv);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there any way you can send byte array? Then decode the bitmap from the other side. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While storing images in internal storage, you have to set the mode to `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` instead of `MODE_PRIVATE`. This is because a widget is handled by the home screen process and it cant access your files if you dont set the mode right.

So replace this line:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("myfile.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("myfile.png", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Also, use `Uri.parse()` and `getPath()` instead of `fromFile()`. `fromFile()` works only on Android 2.2 and above.

```
Uri internal = Uri.Parse(internalFile.getPath());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using `rv.setUri(R.id.widgetImageView, "setImageURI", "file://myfile.png");` instead of `rv.setImageViewUri(R.id.widgetImageView, internal);` seems to load the image correctly. You might want to give that a try.

If that doesn't work there's still the option to scaling down the image so that you can use the `setImageBitmap` method. 
Example:

```
 public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

 final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        

 int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
 int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

 photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

 return photo;
 }
```